# how to tell if oracle database is installed on pc

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, local-storage

i work for a company as java developer, they gave me laptop that was previously used by another person, to test my java application i need to have oracle on laptop and create some sample database with sample data. when I got the laptop i found that there is oracle installed on it, but i don't know if this is only oracle client or full oracle installation (server + client)
please can you tell me how to figure out if there is only oracle client on laptop or full database installation, plus i need to know if there is some default username and password so that i can access the database and create schema and tables in it, so that i can test my java application.
i thinking to see DBA but i thought of dropping a question here first, maybe i can solve the problem by myself

Comment: Your company woudn't answer your questions?

Comment: Linux, Windows or Mac?

Comment: they will but i ama in vacation, and i need to make some stuff readyy before i get back to work. i don't want to tell them that i don't know and please help me. it's not good. i am new employee.

it is windows operating system

Comment: Try to run this command `sqlplus "/ as sysdba"`

Comment: i tried sys/sys on sql plus and also sysdba/sysdba it gives me this:  ora 12560 TNS:protocol adapter error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is an Oracle Client, it doesn't have bin/dbca

Oracle Home may indicate the installation's type. The default Oracle Home folder names are:

- Oracle Database: dbhome_1
- Oracle Client: client_1

Although to make sure, you should check the services looking for OracleServiceSID entry on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Run Command **sqlplus** on command prompt.

Comment: Does this come with the client, database, or both?

Answer (score 3):

Check services of windows to know that the oracle database was installed on laptop or not.

Try to find oracle universal installer in all programs by this also you can get which version of database is installed.

Your second question is about default username/password
For this you can give username : "/ as sysdba".
It will not ask for password because it will authenticate thorugh OS authentication.

after login you can able to create new schema or user and tables.

Answer (score -2):

You can check simply using command prompt. Open command prompt and type `connect`. Provide the username and password and press Enter. It will show "connected" if the database is in your system.

Username: system (default)
Password: (what you provided while installing)

Answer (score -2):

Firstly goto my computer/ this pc and then click on
downloads option and see your app and check that Oracle
is available there or not.